# create-react-app not creating directory on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, create-react-app

I've installed nodejs and npm using sudo apt-get. I've installed create-react-app using `sudo npm install -g create-react-app` but when I try to use create-react-app, it does absolutely nothing.

This
$ create-react-app my-app
did not create a directory.

I tried to make the directory and see if I could get create-react-app to populate it. This
$ mkdir my-app
$ create-react-app my-app
did absolutely nothing too.. The my-app directory stayed completely empty. It didn't even give an en error message.

How do I get create-react-app to work? To create and populate a directory as I think it should?

Update: when I installed create-react-app, I got the following warning. 
npm WARN engine create-react-app@1.3.3: wanted: {"node":">=4"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})

Answer (score 1):

Did you try installing it globally?

i.e.

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
```

or

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

---

`create-react-app` is a command line tool, so it needs to be installed globally in order for you to use it.

Comment: I did and with sudo and -g as well. I did get the following warning though: npm WARN engine create-react-app@1.3.3: wanted: {"node":">=4"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})

Comment: @sebastianspiegel it looks like your node version is 0.10.25, but you need version 4 or greater to use `create-react-app` - https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html - I find switching node versions to be easiest with [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)  i.e. **node version manager**. `nvm` allows you to have multiple versions of Node.js installed and to easily switch between those versions.

Comment: to piggy back on sebastian, nvm is the way to go. Just make sure you've got it set to override the system node or you'll have to keep setting your node version every time you ssh into your server.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I needed to upgrade my version of nodejs using npm. I got the answer from [this](https://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs) website. I skipped the first command that they recommend `$ sudo npm cache clean -f`, but probably should have done it. I used to following two commands.

$ sudo npm install -g n
$ sudo n stable

create-react-app now works fine.